# How to convert an element to a string that can be stored and restored from localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, local-storage

My plan is to store my elements in localStorage once they've been read once (for an online app – I figure that if I can get it to work it will speed up my app significantly). So I came up with the following, but the contents seem to either be stored or come back as null. Now I thought that an element was fundamentally a string so I wouldn't have to do anything with it to store it in localStorage, but apparently not. Does anyone know if it's possible to achieve what I want?

If you want to take it for a spin then you'll need a small file holding html to pass to it. The contents aren't important. The first time it runs `if (content)` will evaluate to false. The next time true and I added the `.clear()` to make it alternate. The third time the showSource function will populate the `id=localor` element (which will need to be separate from the `id=content` element or whatever other element you choose to populate) showing the null after "from File ".

```
function showSource(source) {   //Function and related element only here for testing
    $("#localor").html("<p>"+source+"</p>");
}

//local is the name of the localStorage element
//id is the id of the element in the main form
//source is where the content for the element originates.
    function loadElement(local, id, source) {   

//This is the generic script for attempts to load an element.

        content = localStorage.getItem(local); //Try to load from local storage
    if (content) {//If found
        $(id).html(content);
        showSource("from Local " + content);    //Added only for testing
        localStorage.clear();   //Added only for testing
        //load into the #content element
    } else {//Not found
        $(id).load(source);
        showSource("from File " + content); //Added only for testing
        //so load it from the server..
        localStorage.setItem(local,$(id).html());
        //then save it to the local storage, so we don't have to do this again any time soon.
    }
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    loadElement("login.1001", "#content", "login.html");
});
```

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you're reinventing the browser cache...

Comment: This is one of the (many) situations where walking through the code with a debugger, inspecting variables and such as you go, would tell you the answer (or at least get you on the road to it). Your browser has a debugger built into it. That debugger is your friend. :-)

Comment: Firebug is for Firefox

Comment: @pheromix: Yes, although even Firefox has one built-in now.

Comment: That's probably good advice. I'm yet to work out how to debug any of these languages. I'll look into it the next time I get a serious problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason what you're doing doesn't work is that you're saving the item before it's loaded. `load` works *asynchronously*, like all (reasonable) ajax calls. The process *starts* when you call `load`, but finishes later. Your code is then continuing and grabbing what it thinks is the content and saving it, but the content isn't there yet.

Use the callback instead:

```
$(id).load(source, function() {
    showSource("from File " + content); //Added only for testing
    //so load it from the server..
    localStorage.setItem(local,$(id).html());
    //then save it to the local storage, so we don't have to do this again any time soon.
});
```

---

But...aren't you just reinventing the browser cache?

Comment: As I understand it the browser cache isn't very persistent, but you're correct, I think. Thanks for your help. I'm still getting used to what runs synchronously and what asynchronously.

Comment: It's true that caches get cycled fairly quickly (the default cache size of browsers is surprisingly small), but I'd still just make sure you were cache-friendly rather than storing your pages in local storage. Not least because if everyone starts doing that, local storage will start having the same issue caches do.

Comment: That's definitely a risk. Sadly if I code it in the callback as suggested (even with the word 'content' removed — that was a bug) the script doesn't run at all. I'm confused, which is a frequent state for me in these early days. I tried adding the parameters to the callback function, but that made no difference.

Comment: I was missing a bracket and a semi-colon. It works now. Thanks a lot. This should increase my app's performance significantly :)