# Replace InnerHTML With Cookie Logging

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, replace, element

I've got some javascript code for replacing innerHTML of a element when clicked. Now i've got the code for that and it does work great! But one small issue is that, I want the webserver to remember the change when innerHTML of an element was replaced. So the webserver remembers the change and doesn't return to its default state. Whether with database or in Cookie, sessionStorage, localStorage.

```
document.getElementById("replace1").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("replace1");

function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     localStorage.setItem("replace1",this.responseText);   
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://natevanghacks.com/replacements/yoinkexecutor2.html", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: i see no jQuery here so I removed that tag

Comment: alright, i might of mixed the terms up, in burst of the moment

Comment: You need to have the server save and send it back? so do that with whatever you server is.  localStorage is in the browser so that is not server side, I believe you need to clarify a lot

Comment: I meant client sided, or you can call it browser sided. So localStorage or sessionStorage would be a solution for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert an element to a string that can be stored and restored from localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24956525/how-to-convert-an-element-to-a-string-that-can-be-stored-and-restored-from-local)

Comment: Or maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/48239869/125981

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in AJAX:

```
localStorage.setItem("replace1",this.responseText);
```

And after body onload:

```
document.getElementById("replace1").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("replace1");
```

**Edit**:

```js
  function loadSavedData(){
    var data=localStorage.getItem("replace1");
    document.getElementById("replace1").innerHTML = data?data:'No Data found';
  }
  function deleteData(){
    localStorage.removeItem("replace1");
  }
  function loadDoc() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        localStorage.setItem("replace1",this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("replace1").innerHTML =this.responseText;
        console.log(this.responseText);
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "filename.html", true); //put your filename here...
    xhttp.send();
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="loadDoc()">Send request and load Data
</button>
<button onclick="loadSavedData()">load Saved Data
</button>
<button onclick="deleteData()">Delete saved Data
</button>
<br>
<div id="replace1">
</div>
```

**Note**: You should run this file on `http://` or `https://` protocols only

Comment: I updated the post with the newest code you suggested, I should fix. And the code still doesn't seem to work for some reason. There may be a specific way to make webserver remember the change for XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: @NateVang I think this is cross-domain `XMLHttpRequest` request & this is blocked by `https://natevanghacks.com` read more about [here](http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/how.html)

Comment: Your code will work fine when you send request to your server's files like `xhttp.open("GET", "yourfilename.php", true);`

Comment: the element won't show up now, it outputs "undefined"

Comment: Put your filename in `xhttp.open`, and reload the page

Comment: Ok I edited my answer, try with my code it is working fine

Comment: thats all great thanks for helping, but the problem is when, I refresh the element returns back to its default state again. Unchanged not replaced.